# Safe alternatives for eval() in JavaScript (safety scanners test)

Tags: javascript, eval

I have runned the safety scanner for my application and it says in general:

> "eval() is a dangerous function that executes code with all the privileges of the caller
> sides. If you run eval() on a string that might be affected
> attackers, then you can run malicious code on the device
> user with rights to your web page/extension."

That is my code before

```
Date.createNewFormat = function(format) {
    console.log('format 22', format)
    var funcName = "format" + Date.formatFunctions.count++;
    Date.formatFunctions[format] = funcName;
    var code = "Date.prototype." + funcName + " = function() {return ";
    var special = false;
    var ch = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < format.length; ++i) {
        ch = format.charAt(i);
        if (!special && ch == "\\") {
            special = true;
        } else {
            if (special) {
                special = false;
                code += "'" + String.escape(ch) + "' + ";
            } else {
                code += Date.getFormatCode(ch);
            }
        }
    }
    eval(code.substring(0, code.length - 3) + ";}");
}
```

so changed eval for new Function and I don't know if that can fix error in the scanner test

```
var runFunction = new Function(code.substring(0, code.length - 3) + ";}");
runFunction();
```

Comment: The problems with `eval()` are shared equally with creating Function instances from strings of code. Why do you think you need to do it? What are you trying to accomplish? You can do very nearly everything you think you need to do by constructing strings of code by instead using proper techniques of building functions in closures.

Comment: The issues with `eval()` mainly apply to code that's generated from untrustworthy input. If you're constructing the code yourself, that doesn't arise.

Comment: In your case, all the embedded code comes from `Date.getFormatCode(ch)`. Assuming you control this, your original code is safe.

Comment: @Barmar also assuming that `String.escape` is safe

Comment: It looks like you're trying to add functions to the `Date` prototype dynamically. Read [Don't modify object you don't own](https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/) for more.

Comment: If NodeJS is an option, there are projects like [isolated-vm](https://github.com/laverdet/isolated-vm) that can be used to run untrusted code in an isolated context (sandbox). The chunk `else { if ... } else` is the same as `else if { ... } else` here because of how the logic will fall through. Is there a solid reason this needs to attach to Date and can't be it's own "class"?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of constructing the format function as a string that you `eval()`, you can evaluate the format string when

```
Date.createNewFormat = function(format) {
    console.log('format 22', format)
    let funcName = "format" + Date.formatFunctions.count++;
    Date.formatFunctions[format] = funcName;
    let funcArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < format.length; ++i) {
        let ch = format[i];
        if (ch == "\\" && i < format.length-1) {
            // use next character literally and skip over it
            i++;
            funcArray.push(() => format[i]);
        } else {
            funcArray.push(Date.getFormatCode(ch));
        }
    }
    Date.prototype[funcName] = function() {
        return funcArray.map(f => f.call(this));
    }
}
```

You'll need to change `Date.getFormatCode()` so instead of returning code as strings, it returns functions. The functions should refer to `this` to access the `Date` object being formatted (as I assume your string versions do) and return the formatted value.

Comment: `funcArray.push(() => format[i++]);` is wrong, `i` must be incremented immediately and outside of the closure

Comment: Thanks. That was left over from an earlier version that was iterating in the returned function, instead of constructing an array of functions.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but you'll need to `let`-declare `i` for this to work, or use `ch = format[i++]` and `() => ch`